# How to sync clipboard between ubuntu desktop and android phone?

Tags: software-recommendation, android

Is there's any way by which I can sync clipboard Ubuntu 12.04/14.04 with android phone  with JellyBean 4.1.2 preferably over same wifi network or over internet if that's not possible. In windows there's a app called ClipSync to sync clipboard b/w pc and android device.

Is there's any app comparable to ClipSync in windows or any other. Even though android is Linux based but  have nothing much to do with Ubuntu really. please help me out I have googled everywhere but didn't had anything close to it.

Comment: I use Google Docs for that purpose, however I consider your question a very good one. I was facing more or less the same challenge.

Comment: I'm looking for that as well. Most solutions use "PC" as synonym of "Windows", which is sad =/

Answer (score 8):

Finally, got an app called KDE connect which can be used to sync clipboard and many other additional features are also there. But it is available by default for Ubuntu 14.04 in software center, but **in order to use this app one will have to install KDE**- system setting from Ubuntu software center along with KDE connect app from google play.

1. Install KDE connect from Ubuntu software center

   [image]
2. Install KDE system setting from Ubuntu software center

   [image]
3. Install KDE connect on android from google play [KDE connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp)
4. Pair the device and pc by opening KDE connect from KDE system setting.

   [image]

Answer (score 4):

There are two different ways to install KDE connect on gnome based systems like Ubuntu. Both make use of the Gnome Extensions and the KDE connect Android App on mobile.

### Method 1: GS Connect Extension (Easier and more stable)

1. Install the Android app on your mobile [from Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp).
2. Install the [GSConnect Extension from Gnome Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/). In this method you don't require the software from the Software Center.
3. After you have installed the components, you connect the devices to the same
   network and pair the devices. Once paired, you will have access to a
   whole list of features (see above links for details). Ensure that
   the 'Clipboard Sync' feature is enabled in both the devices.

Detailed instructions can be read on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki/Installation#standard).

[image: screenshot]

### Method 2: KDE Connect + M Connect Extension

1. Install the Android app on your mobile from Google Play store
   ([Click here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp)).
2. Install KDE Connect application on Ubuntu from
   the Software Center. On cosmic *18.10) you have the option to either
   install from the repo or a snap app. Both work the same.
3. Install the MConnect Extension from Gnome Extensions ([Click here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1272/mconnect/))
4. After you have installed the components, you connect the devices to the same
   network and pair the devices. Once paired, you will have access to a
   whole list of features (see above links for details). Ensure that
   the 'Sync Clipboard' feature is enabled in both the devices.

Comment: method 1 worked like a charm, had to uninstall snap firefox and install APT firefox afterward, but it's totally worth it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Gnome Shell alternative to KDE Connect which is called [DeskCon](https://github.com/screenfreeze/deskcon-desktop) ([Homepage](http://screenfreeze.net/deskcon/))

EDIT: [Notice](http://screenfreeze.net/my-condolence/)

Comment: I think is very beta now .. :( but I hope it will be a good solution in the future

Comment: I installed the packages `deskcon-server` and `deskcon-indicator` which provides me with [this tray icon](http://i.imgur.com/BM1nAZ4.png). However, its context menu entries don't open any window on Ubuntu 16.04. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it:

1. Install google chrome or chromium on Ubuntu.
2. Install [Pushbullet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pushbullet/chlffgpmiacpedhhbkiomidkjlcfhogd?hl=en) Chrome extension
3. Install Pushbullet on Android from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android&hl=en)
4. Allow chrome on your PC to run in background (this is the default setting btw)
5. Enable universal copy paste (big giant option on Pushbullet app)

And voila, this will sync clipboard across all your devices on any network securely.

This will also sync android notifications, though you can disable those if you wanted to.

Comment: Since a recent update, the Universal Copy and Paste feature is only available with a paid subscription, which made Pushbullet kind of useless for me.

Comment: Is it a copy/paste by cloud? I need local only solution.

Answer (score 1):

i came to find this solution myself, but i'm a very clumsy software installer.
so i turned to existing solutions:

you may send an email message to yourself, with any attachments.

for users of telegram: you can paste text and upload files to your "Saved Messages" virtual contact, on any telegram client, and find it on another client in the same place.

for google users: google keep may hold text and some media and has a web client and mobile apps.