# Sharing the same clipboard with windows

Tags: 14.04, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I run Ubuntu and Windows 10 machines. Is it possible somehow share same clipboard contents. Not keyboard and mouse sharing - just clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution for your problem is ***Pushbullet*** which came with that purpose and is also great!

I used that in the past between Windows, Linux, and Android but would not remember the whole process again since I'm not in Windows anymore, but, it's easy once you have installed in Linux it would communicate through wifi the same app Linux-Windows and both share.

Other options are KDE connect. (I believe it is possible to configure more advanced actions inside this program for advanced users).

*Different suggestions, ideas, and tools...*
[Link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364566/how-to-sync-clipboard-between-ubuntu-desktop-and-android-phone/1088656)
[Link 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp)
[Link 3](http://screenfreeze.net/deskcon/)
[Link 4](https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/)
[Link 5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35030/how-can-i-copy-paste-data-to-and-from-the-windows-clipboard-to-an-opensuse-clipb)